# How make a callback class iterable instead of storing all callback parameters

Tags: python, callback, iterator, coroutine

I have a 3rd party library with a parser that expects a callback class with a `new_token` method. So far, my callback class and my token processing looks like this:

```
class MySink(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokens = []

    def new_token(self, token):
        self.tokens.append(token)

sink = MySink()
p = ThirdPartyParser(sink)
p.parse("my_data_file")

for t in sink.tokens:
    print t
```

The token list can get very long (leading to memory problems) so I'd like to turn `MySink` into an iterable class where the tokens don't have to be stored in a list but are "pulled" on the fly and the parsing is stopped while the token is processed. Something like this:

```
class MyIterableSink(object): # incomplete!
    def new_token(self, token):
        # TODO:
        # Store token for next iteration step
        # halt execution like with 'yield', wait for next iteration step

sink = MyIterableSink()
p = ThirdPartyParser(sink)
p.parse("my_data_file")

for t in sink:
    print t
```

How do I have to modify the `MyIterableSink` class? Is something like this possible? I can't modify the parser class, only the callback class. I know I have to implement `__iter__` and `__next__` methods and use coroutines where probably the tokens are sent with the `send` method but can't quite wrap my head around it. Any code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not sure what you mean by that. For me "Container" implies that all the tokens are stored internally (like the class does now). I don't want that. Instead, I want only one token to be stored at a time.

Comment: I edited the example code to make it clearer. The tokens are pushed into the class with the `new_token` callback.

Comment: Are the callbacks asynchronous?

Comment: No, the callbacks are synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
p.parse("my_data_file")
```

must be calling `new_token` in a loop. Since you can't change the way the third-party parser works, you are not in control of the way `new_token` gets called. Making `MySink` an iterator is not going to work since `p.parse` is not iterating over `sink`. So instead of making `sink` an iterator, simply process the tokens as `new_token` is called:

```
class MySink(object): 
    def new_token(self, token):
        # process token
        print(token)

sink = MyIterableSink()
p = ThirdPartyParser(sink)
p.parse("my_data_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the callbacks are asynchronous, you can use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#queue-objects):

```
class MySink(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.tokens = Queue()

    def new_token(self, token):
        self.tokens.put(token)

    def __iter__(self):
        token = self.tokens.get()
        while token is not None:
            yield token
            token = self.tokens.get()
```

Note that you have to specify a stop condition for your iterator, like a timeout or a special token value (`None` in the example above).

EDIT:
Since your callbacks are synchronous, unutbu said it all in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29253022/2846140).